# Make Field Element Receive Droppable

Tags: jquery, input, textbox, field

I can drag and drop any file from my file window into certain fields, like my url bar, and get the file address. Is there a way to have this happen with a textbox or input element via jquery or regular html attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 drag and drop: http://html5demos.com/drag and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/